# How do I run Hive queries on a cloud platform like AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

I've run Pig scripts on an AWS EMR cluster, but have no experience with Hive. I'm trying to understand how to run Hive queries and scripts on the data in HDFS because there needs to be a database and table setup.

Am I supposed to setup the database and table before running the Hive query or script? A hive query obviously is supposed to have a `FROM` clause, but how do I know which table and database to designate in that `FROM` clause?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create an **External Table**, which defines the table to Hive in SQL-like syntax, but points to the data that is already present on disk.

Refer to any Hive documentation, such as https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial